# Sanitizing HTML using Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, sanitize

I'm trying to clean up some CMS entered HTML that has extraneous paragraph tags and br tags everywhere. The Sanitize gem has proved very useful to do this but I am stuck with a particular issue.

The problem is when there is a br tag directly after/before a paragraph tag eg

```
<p>
  <br />
  Some text here
  <br />
  Some more text
  <br />
</p>
```

I would like to strip out the extraneous first and last br tags, but not the middle one.

I'm very much hoping I can use a sanitize transformer to do this but can't seem to find the right matcher to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with sanitize but `/<br \/>(.*)<br \/>/` will match the middle portion without the leading an trailing `<br />` tags.

Comment: Don't use regexp to manipulate HTML. It's way too fragile of a solution.

Comment: And, you really need to show us what you've tried. That lets us know you're wanting to know how to fish, not just asking for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to locate the particular `<br>` nodes that are contained by `<p>`:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<p>
  <br />
  Some text here
  <br />
  Some more text
  <br />
</p>
EOT

doc.search('p > br').map(&:to_html)
# => ["<br>", "<br>", "<br>"]
```

Once we know we can find them, it's easy to remove specific ones:

```
br_nodes = doc.search('p > br')
br_nodes.first.remove
br_nodes.last.remove
doc.to_html
# => "<p>\n  \n  Some text here\n  <br>\n  Some more text\n  \n</p>\n"
```

Notice that Nokogiri removed them, but their associated Text nodes that are their immediate siblings, containing their "\n" are left behind. A browser will gobble those up and not display the line-ends, but you might be feeling OCD, so here's how to remove those also:

```
br_nodes = doc.search('p > br')
[br_nodes.first, br_nodes.last].each do |br|
  br.next_sibling.remove
  br.remove
end
doc.to_html
# => "<p>\n  <br>\n  Some more text\n  </p>\n"
```

Comment: Hi the Tin Man - many thanks for your help, in the end I managed to get a working version continuing the approach I was taking - I posted it here so you can see that I managed to catch a fish myself, but can now improve my technique thanks to the advice of a more experience angler :)

Answer (score 0):

```
initial_linebreak_transformer = lambda {|options|
  node = options[:node]
  if node.present? && node.element? && node.name.downcase == 'p'
    first_child = node.children.first
    if first_child.name.downcase == 'br'
      first_child.unlink
      initial_linebreak_transformer.call options
    end
  end
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing it a slower, more difficult way. Instead of checking to see if the node is present, it's an element and its name is `'p'`, tell Nokogiri to find the nodes using a CSS or XPath selector; At that point you KNOW all those things and can simple do what you want to with that node. It's a LOT faster to let libXML do it than to iteratively do that for every node. I'd strongly recommend running benchmarks to prove/disprove your current method as a big or complex HTML document will be costly to process.

Comment: Thanks again - I will definitely try your approach in preference. I got the basis from this : https://github.com/vjt/sanitize-rails/blob/master/example/sanitizer.rb#L22-L27 as I am using sanitizer & that was the most relevant code I found to start to find a way to get the result I wanted. Totally agree that it's better to use libXML. Hope that makes sense & thanks again for your advice.